# Using pointer to channel

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

Is it good practice to use pointer to channel? For example I read the data concurrently and pass those data `map[string]sting` using channel  and process this channel inside `getSameValues()`.

```
func getSameValues(results *chan map[string]string) []string {
    var datas = make([]map[string]string, len(*results))
    i := 0
    for values := range *results {
        datas[i] = values
        i++
    }
}
```

The reason I do this is because the `chan map[string]string` there will be around millions of data inside the map and it will be more than one map.

So I think it would be a good approach if I can pass pointer to the function so that it will not copy the data to save some resource of memory.

I didn't find a good practice in [effective go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels). So I'm kinda doubt about my approach here.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is poor practice to use pointers to channels, maps, functions, interfaces, or slices for efficiency.

Values of these types have a small fixed size independent of the length or capacity of the value. An internal pointer references the variable size data.

Channels, maps, and functions are the same size as a pointer. Therefore, the runtime cost of copying a value of these types is identical to copying a pointer to the value.

Interfaces are two × the size of a pointer, and slices are three × the size of a pointer. The cost of copying a value of these types is higher than copying a pointer. That extra copying cost is often lower or equal to the cost of dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: Size of interface depends on what the interface contains, it's not just 2 times size of pointer, isn't it?

Comment: @Eric an internal pointer references the variable size data in an interface value.

Comment: Ok, you mean if a function declare a param as an interface which contains methods, and then pass instance of an struct which impl the interface, then only 2 bytes are passed? For example, in this link: https://codeshare.io/vwd6Mn , when I call `passInterface()` and pass a struct (not struct pointer), what's actually passed is 2 bytes?

Comment: @Eric See https://research.swtch.com/interfaces for a detailed description of interface internals (some parts of the article are dated, but it’s the only article that I know of that describes the memory layout in detail).

Comment: I've read the link, it's written in 2009 when go still impl in `c` at least partly. Anyway it mentioned there are 2 pointers in an interface.

Comment: @CeriseLimón What about struct? Especially big struct. Seems like it is good idea to pass a pointer to struct into channel?

Comment: @sprutex  It is often appropriate to use a pointer as the channel element type.  The question and my answer discuss using a pointer to the channel itself, not the channel element type.

Answer (score 25):

In Go, there are six categories of value that are passed by reference rather than by value. These are pointers, slices, maps, channels, interfaces and functions.

Copying a reference value and copying a pointer should be considered equal in terms of what the CPU has to actually do (at least as a good approximation).

So it is almost never useful to use pointers to channels, just like it is rarely useful to use pointers to maps.

Because your channel carries maps, the channel is a reference type and so are the maps, so all the CPU is doing is copying pointers around the heap. In the case of the channel, it also does goroutine synchronisation too.

For further reading, open [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) and search the page for the word 'reference'.

Comment: "five categories of value that are passed by reference" --- actually everything in Go is passed by value. https://golang.org/doc/faq#pass_by_value "As in all languages in the C family, everything in Go is passed by value."

Comment: Yes that's true, perhaps I was over-simplifying: the five categories are all reference types and copying a reference (or passing a reference parameter) does not copy the thing it refers to. One might argue that saying everything is passed by value is an over-simplification in a different sense. I need to understand whether changes I make to a parameter I'm passed will have any effect beyond the scope of the value.

Comment: There are six categories of value passed by reference; I've added functions to the list. (thanks to @human)

Comment: There are no any categories: everything is passed as a value.

Comment: Yes and no. See my earlier reply. Just because the formality is pass by value doesn't mean you can ignore the effect of modifying a reference value.

Comment: There is no such thing as reference value. They all are just values with no special properties. Which of them do you think needs a special treatment?

Comment: Yes there is. What is the side effect of a function that takes an int value then modifies that int? Nothing. What is the side effect of a function that takes a map value then modifies the map? The caller's map is altered.

Comment: Example mutation of a map parameter: https://play.golang.org/p/3DGkAdIOC0l.
The int is not modified outside `modifyInt` because it is passed by value as-is. The map *is* modified. Although the map is also passed by value, because it is a reference type (as I call it), its content is altered by `modifyMap`.

Comment: You only confuse beginners: if you don't treat map special - you have less to learn and remember. Map is a structure that holds a pointer to its data storage. As simple as that. No references, no magic  The same story with slices and arrays: see - no need to remember they are special, isn't it convenient?

Comment: "then modifies that int" --- you don't modify an int, you override a variable value: that's where you miss a point and bring magic to explain the behaviour. See, maps are not passed by reference: https://play.golang.org/p/oOYHC5S1gOC If they were - the value outside would be a `foo: bar`

Comment: This discussion is pointless because we have different terminologies. The map parameter in your example is not a pointer to a map, so obviously it does not change the external value. That was not the point I was making.

Comment: "so obviously it does not change the external value" --- that's right, but if it was a reference - it would have been changing. "because we have different terminologies" --- that's correct, you use a term that is not well defined, that's why your explanation is confusing (because it makes assumptions nobody else is aware of). You may have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing if you want to improve your answer. "it does not change the external value" --- that's correct, you use it in your example though: https://play.golang.org/p/3DGkAdIOC0l (line 20)

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/3DGkAdIOC0l --- have a look at your example again: you're appealing between statements 20 and 16. Do you not see those are _different_? That's why I provided https://play.golang.org/p/oOYHC5S1gOC which you than called "obviously does not change". My point here: if you want to prove something, your examples should be consistent: as long as `v = 7` is valid to prove something, so should be `m = map[string]string{"foo": "bar"}` too

Answer (score 15):

Everything in Golang is passed by value. Even pointers are a type and assigned the value of the memory address. So they are values too.

(Extending Rick's answer) There are actually **six** types that hold pointer values and a pointer to these (i.e. a pointer to a pointer) types doesn't help anyway:

1. pointers
2. slices
3. maps
4. channels
5. interfaces
6. function

Comment: Thanks for the correction - I missed functions as values. I'll correct the original post.

Comment: They all are passed by values.

Comment: Absolutely, they are all passed by value. But the value is the address itself. Will update the answer to be clear

Comment: Add struct to the list. Example: `struct { p * int }`.